# Не сохраняется конфигурация платежного способа в Virtuemart

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, virtuemart

Разрабатываю платежный модуль для Virtuemart. Конфигурационный файл `test_payment.xml` выглядит следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="2.5" type="plugin" group="vmpayment" method="upgrade">
    <name>VM Payment - Test</name>
    <author>Test</author>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <description>Test payment</description>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="test_payment">test_payment.php</filename>
    </files>
    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">
                <field name="merchant" type="text" size="20" label="Логин" description="" default="" />
                <field name="password"  type="text" size="20" label="Пароль" description="" default="" />
                <field name="test" type="list" default="1" label="Режим теста" description="">
                    <option value="1">Включен</option>
                    <option value="0">Выключен</option>
                </field>
                <field name="step" type="list" default="1" label="Стадийность" description="">
                    <option value="1">Одностадийный платеж</option>
                    <option value="2">Двухстадийный платеж</option>
                </field>
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

При добавлении нового способа оплаты и сохранении конфигурации в БД в таблицу `virtuemart_paymentmethods` в поле `payment_params` сохраняется следующая строчка:

```
merchant="test"|password="test"|test="0"|step="2"|
```

Но при этом на странице конфигурации все равно остаются поля пустыми/по умолчанию. Подскажите, почему после сохранения настроек они не выводятся на странице?

Joomla v3.5.1, Virtuemart v3.0.14

Comment: каким образом ваш xml связан с данными, которые сохраняются в базе и данными, которые выводятся на страницу? В данной интерпретации вопроса связи между этими компонентами нет никакой.

Comment: @MasterAlex реализация сохранения и вывода данных скрыта в классе-родителе `vmPlugin`. Разработчику необходимо только написать правильный `xml`.

Comment: Попробуйте очистить кэш

Comment: наверное ответ очевиден, если данные отправлены и они в базе, и невыводятся после отправки, то возможно необходимо выложить тот файлик в котором оно должно отображатся, и там будут стандартные значения которые не подгружаются с базы, или он некорректно подгружает с базы !!!   вобщем надо код той части которая отображает, код  ключика туту роли не играет.....я так думаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оказалось, что для VirtueMart версии 3 нужно переопределить метод `plgVmDeclarePluginParamsPaymentVM3` класса `vmPSPlugin`:

```
function plgVmDeclarePluginParamsPaymentVM3(&$data) {
    return $this->declarePluginParams('payment', $data);
}
```